# count down timer in react

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.seconds !== 0) {
            this.setState({ seconds: nextProps.seconds });
            setInterval(() => this.getStopTimer(this.state.seconds - 1), 1000);
        }
    }
```

I have this piece of code to make a stopwatch in reactjs.

So in each second it calls a method `getStopTimer` and decrease the second by one and then show in the browser using `{this.state.seconds}`.

I have only a mere idea about lifecycle hooks in react as I am new to this.

The countdown timer is working on my first input, but when I gave another time for it to begin without reloading, the timer is running double the previous time. Like for the first run, the stopwatch was for a 1-second timer, but the next input runs the same by 2 seconds.

Can  you please explain why this is happening?

```
getStopTimer(seconds) {
        console.log(seconds);
        if (seconds >= 0) {
            this.setState({ seconds });
        }
    }
```

here is the stopwatch child component;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Stopwatch extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            hour: 0,
            minute: 0,
            second: 0,
            seconds: 0
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.seconds !== 0) {
            this.setState({ seconds: nextProps.seconds });
            setInterval(() => this.getStopTimer(this.state.seconds - 1), 1000);
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {}

    getStopTimer(seconds) {
        console.log(seconds);
        if (seconds >= 0) {
            this.setState({ seconds });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{this.state.seconds} seconds remains!</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Stopwatch;
```

Comment: can you show the full code of parent and child component?

Comment: I have a stopwatch component and i am calling it within the parent component as this; <Stopwatch seconds={this.state.seconds} />

Comment: You probably need to `clearInterval()` before setting a new one. You also need to clear it in the `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle hook. To explain, if you don't clear, you'll have 2 `setInterval` running concurrently, hence removing 2 seconds each second. Makes sense?

Comment: so what should i be doing inside the componentWillUnmount? clearinterval()?

Comment: @KevinRED this is what you want ?
 https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/1w86k4wj/

Comment: @MayankShukla he's also reinitializing the timer without reloading the page, setting the timer value through props passed from a parent. In the parent, the seconds passed to initialize the timer come from the state, so we have to assume they can be modified on the fly without the child component being unmounted. Hence the need to clear & set interval timers in the `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: @Jaxx Mayank is using clearInterval though. Is the code in the given JSFiddle enough?

Comment: @MayankShukla your solution, when i start again with any number bu typing begins the timer from the previous value state

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the timers you set, or they will keep running, adding an extra second removal for each step everytime you change the props.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Stopwatch extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            hour: 0,
            minute: 0,
            second: 0,
            seconds: 0,
            intervalID: undefined
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.seconds !== 0) {
            if (this.state.intervalID) {
                clearInterval(this.state.intervalID);
            }
            // this.setState({ seconds: nextProps.seconds });
            // this.setState({ intervalID: setInterval(() => this.getStopTimer(this.state.seconds - 1), 1000)});
            // a better alternative to the 2 lines above
            this.setState({
              seconds: nextProps.seconds,
              intervalID: setInterval(() => this.getStopTimer(nextProps.seconds - 1), 1000)
            });
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.state.intervalID) {
            clearInterval(this.state.intervalID);
        }
    }
    ... rest of your code ...
```

Comment: i have a button tag, and i only want to start thr timer once it is clicked? So how would i do that

Comment: That's a different question we can get into, but is your initial problem solved?

Comment: my initial problem is not solved actually. Cause the timer keeps on starting from the first seconds I submitted. Example; Let's say i typed 10s initially and the timer worls perfect. But after that if i want to start another time say 15s, the timer starts from 10s onwards yet again

Comment: **So the timers still countdown 2+ seconds at a time then? Because THAT is the problem you asked a solution for.** Timer initialization is another issue, your code doesn't even show how the timers are invoked by parent components, or how the timers are supposed to start.

Comment: Okay, sorry. The countdown problem of 2+ is solved. Thanks a lot for that. Now what i am having trouble is, rather than statring the timer from a time that we input, i want the timer to run from a time that i submit via a button. What should i do for that?